# How to extract the first word from a string in VBA (Excel)?

Tags: vba, excel

For example, if I had:

```
Sub TestModule()
    Dim test As String
    test = "Machine Head"
End Sub
```

How would I extract the word Machine and assign it to a variable?
I have tried using the Search and Left functions but have not had much success.

Cheers!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use Split():

```
Sub TestModule()
    Dim test As String
    dim frstWrd as string
    test = "Machine Head"
    frstWrd = split(test," ")(0)
    Debug.Print frstWrd
End Sub
```